# Not able to see opened Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

The below code creates and opens a new Excel instance, but I couldn't see the opened Excel in my system despite setting the `Visible` property to `True`.

Could anyone help me with this?

```
Set Exobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set Newbook = Exobj.Workbooks.Add()

Exobj.Application.Visible = True

Newbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\Test6.xlsx")

Exobj.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Project Folder\Test6.xlsx")
```

Comment: What happens when you run just the first 3 lines? Does Excel show up in the task bar? Does it show up in the processes tab of the task manager?

Comment: I believe you need to make the Excel *object* visible. E.g. `Exobj.Visible = True`

Comment: Strange behavior of Excel.Application is often caused by zombies (not properly terminated instences of Excel left over from previous runs of the script). As Ansgar said: Use the Task manager to look whether you have *no* Excel before and exactly one Excel while running in the task list.

Comment: Yes, after clearing excel in process in task manager and adding Exobj.Visible as true, am able to see it. Thank you all.

Comment: Please submit that as your own answer and accept later to avoid additional efforts from community. @Ekkehard.Horner - I'd submit your comment as an answer, that would be fair for OP to accept it)

Answer (score 4):

Strange behavior of Excel.Application is often caused by zombies (not properly terminated instences of Excel left over from previous runs of the script). As Ansgar said: Use the Task manager to look whether you have no Excel before and exactly one Excel while running in the task list.

**Added:**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13921745/603855) for some background and a strategy to avoid Excel zombies.