# How to handle E_INVALIDARG in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, automation

I have implemented a COM automation interface for my application (which is in C++). The application is automated via VBScript.

My question pertains to error handling in the VB script. Some argument values are considered invalid by my implementation of the COM interface, which returns E_INVALIDARG to indicate this. When this occurs, the VB script displays a message box and terminates. Is there a way to handle the error in VB Script (maybe catch an exception somehow?) and avoid the script from terminating?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13628160/603855

Comment: Thanks! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.